# How do I add a new key to a jq array whenever a a key/value repeats itself

Tags: json, duplicates, jq, key-value

This is the input json. In this example json the key/value... "foo:bar" keeps repeating randomly. Order is not important eventhough it looks to be repeating alternately.

```
[
  {
    "foo": "bar",
    "id": "baz"
  },
  {
    "thud": "grunt",
    "id": "fum"
  },
  {
    "foo": "bar",
    "id": "noot"
  },
  {
    "zot": "toto",
    "id": "pluto"
  },
  {
    "foo": "bar",
    "id": "toto"
  }  
]
```

Whenever a key/value gets repeated, rather than removing it, would want to add an additional key/value into that particular element as shown below
The desired output would be:

```
[
  {
    "foo": "bar",
    "id": "baz"
  },
  {
    "thud": "grunt",
    "id": "fum"
  },
  {
    "foo": "bar",
    "id": "noot",
    "desc": "1st duplicate found
  },
  {
    "zot": "toto",
    "id": "pluto"
  },
  {
    "foo": "bar",
    "id": "toto",
    "desc": "2nd duplicate found"
  } 
]
```

Again order and numbering is not relevant/required. Added it for articulation purposes only

Found several solution to remove duplicates but unable to make any headway to resolve this

Appreciate any proposed resolution for above

Thanks much for you time

Tried complex solution to split the json into two and merge with -n and argjson without much break through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach using `tostream` and `fromstream` to deconstruct and reconstruct the input via stream representation, which is a stream of arrays containing a path and its corresponding value. A `foreach` loop iterates over this streams, replicating each item for later reconstruction. Additionally, it keeps track of each path-value pair reduced by the path's first item (matches occur irrelevant of their position in the original input array), and registers each appearance using a counter. If that is higher than one, also output another item (distinguished by adding `_dup` to the last path item) with the current count as value.

```bash
fromstream(
  foreach (tostream | [., (.[0] |= .[1:] | @json)]) as [$s,$j] (
    {};
    if $s | has(1) then .[$j] += 1 end;
    if .[$j] > 1 then [($s[0] | last += "_dup"), .[$j]] else empty end,
    $s
  )
)
```

```json
[
  {
    "foo": "bar",
    "id": "baz"
  },
  {
    "thud": "grunt",
    "id": "fum"
  },
  {
    "foo_dup": 2,
    "foo": "bar",
    "id": "noot"
  },
  {
    "zot": "toto",
    "id": "pluto"
  },
  {
    "foo_dup": 3,
    "foo": "bar",
    "id": "toto"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/mdEYdYZXHYp)

Comment: Excellent @pmf. Exactly what was required. Thanks much. Accepted as answer

Comment: Wanted to process the output further and use it in cli.
Keep getting syntax error as below

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
fromstream( foreach (tostream | [., (.[0] |= .[1:] | @json)]) as [$s,$j] ( {}; if $s | has(1) then .[$j] += 1 end; if .[$j] > 1 then [($s[0] | last += "_dup"), .[$j]] else empty end, $s ) )                                                                                                            
```

Comment: above provided solution is working seamlessly in jqplay web interface but the same is throwing syntax errors when executed through jq cli in bash console

Comment: @anantha Aha. you might be using an outdated version of jq; jqplay.org currently runs on version 1.7.1. For instance, jq v1.6 (from 2018) still required "full" `if` expressions, i.e. with the `else` branch always present, which for the above is given only in the second instance. In this case, try replacing the first `end` with `else . end`. Going back even further, jq v1.4 (from 2014), for example, didn't yet implement deconstructions like `as [$s,$j]`, and fixing that would be a bigger issue. Better update jq to a recent version (all of them are available as binaries, no installation needed).

Comment: that did it. brew upgrade jq did the trick. it's been sometime since I upgraded jq on my machine. Currently it was v1.6. Was working fine for all my queries so did not bother upgrading till now

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy-to-understand solution, or at least it's a solution to one interpretation of the problem.  It has the advantage that it can easily be modified in accordance with other interpretations of the problem.

```
reduce .[] as $kv ({ ans: [], count: {}};
  ($kv|del(.id)|tostring) as $pair
  | .count[$pair] += 1
  | .count[$pair] as $count
  | if $count == 1 then .ans += [$kv]
    else .ans += [$kv + {desc: "duplicate #\($count) of \($pair)"} ]
    end)
  | .ans
```

Sample output:

```
[
  {
    "foo": "bar",
    "id": "baz"
  },
  {
    "thud": "grunt",
    "id": "fum"
  },
  {
    "foo": "bar",
    "id": "noot",
    "desc": "duplicate #2 of {\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
  },
  {
    "zot": "toto",
    "id": "pluto"
  },
  {
    "foo": "bar",
    "id": "toto",
    "desc": "duplicate #3 of {\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
  }
]
```